# Metal Memor Leak

Tags: swift, memory, metal

I've got a leak in my metal pipeline and I don't know where...

I've tried Malloc Stack Diagnostics and it pointed at the creation of the metal device and the app delegate. So not really sure where to look.

Any debug tips?

[image: memory leak]
[image: malloc stack]
[image: leak instrument]

I'm on to something, the leak is pointing at my command buffer [here](https://github.com/hexagons/pixels/blob/feature/live/Source/PixelsRender.swift#L188).

I'm switching between some threads, mainly back to main from some completion handlers. What thread should I be doing the render setup on?

**Update:**

I'm testing to move all my render setup to a background thread:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "render", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .never, target: nil)
queue.async {
    // Render Setup
}
```

Comment: There's almost nothing to go on here. How did you determine there's a leak. What does "I've tried Malloc Stack" mean, specifically — what exactly did you do — and in what way did it point at the creation of the Metal device and app delegate? Have you tried the Leaks instrument?

Comment: @KenThomases I've updated the post with some images. I'll look in to the Leaks instrument.